# Enable anonymous access in SharePoint 2010 not working, cant access my SharePoint site anonymous

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, anonymous

I have tried to enable anonymous access in SharePoint 2010 for quite a while now, but it just won't work. I have followed many of the guides out there to enable anonymous access, eg [Enable Anonymous Access in SharePoint 2010](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010).

When I try to access my SharePoint site anonymously I don't get any login dialog, but I get a **403 FORBIDDEN error**.

I have checked that the "Anonymous Authentication" is enabled in the IIS. I get the same error regardless browser.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Commented out all the code that has SPContext.Current and then it works. Read this blog post: http://steveclements.net/blog/Gotcha-403-and-401-errors-in-SharePoint-using-Anonymous-access.